# How to combine GIDSignIn.signIn() and GIDSignIn.addScopes() into one step for user

Tags: api, swiftui, gidsignin

I am making an app that requests data from the Gmail API on iOS using SwiftUI. I was wondering if there is a way to combine the two aforementioned steps into open. Currently, iOS asks the user to open up a signing window, the user signs in, and then iOS asks the user to sign in with and alert again. This is not good UI and I'm hoping, though I'm a beginner, that I can do better!

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: signinConfig, presenting: (UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.rootViewController)!) { giduser, err in
             GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.addScopes(["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose"], presenting: (UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.rootViewController)!) { user, error in
                if let user = user {
                    self.googleUser = user
                    self.signedIn = true
                } else if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                } else {
                   print("Error")
                }
            }
        }
```